# Alert when detecting a specific number of shards on index

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert, metricbeat

I would like to detect when a number of shards per index passes some threshold.

I use Metricbeat with Elasticsearch module to retrieve metrics data from indices and ElastAlert to send alerts when some number of shards per index is detected.

At first, I thought I could somehow use the `_stats` API or `_settings` endpoint in order to access the number of shards per index and run ElastAlert on this number. However, as far as I know, ElastAlert scans only the `_doc` section of indices, and not `_stats` or `_settings`.

As written in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/6.7/exported-fields-elasticsearch.html) of Elasticsearch module of Metricbeat, there is a `elasticsearch.cluster.stats.indices.shards.count` field which lists the number of shards for the whole *cluster*:

> **`elasticsearch.cluster.stats.indices.shards.count`**
>     type: long
>
> Total number of shards in cluster.

I wonder if there is something similar to that but for each *index*? If not, what are the possible workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

The number of shards per index is not something that grows over time.

By default the ***number of shards*** for a specific index will be **1** and the ***number of replicas*** will be also **1** (Elasticsearch 7.X).

You can [specify](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#create-index-settings) the number of shards for a specific index either by mapping or with an index template otherwise you get the default sharding defined by elasticsearch.

Refer to [this article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster) or [this video](https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/conf/2016/sf/quantitative-cluster-sizing) to see how to decide how many shards and replicas you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately, there are two issues:
1. There have been a lot of indexes with different number of shards in the past (and may be in the future), so there is a need to automatically scan for that number.
2. I don't have control over indexes and their mapping as these are created and maintained by others, and I just monitor them.

Comment: Monitoring the number of shards per index is not a good idea, you should be monitoring the shard size per index or the number of shards per Gb of memory.